# Getting "Protocol Not Available" Error When Executing Docker Commands in Windows PowerShell GitLab Runner

Tags: docker, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm attempting to build a Windows Docker image using a GitLab pipeline. The GitLab Runner is configured to use the shell (PowerShell) executor and is hosted on an AWS Windows EC2 instance where Docker is already installed.

In the pipeline, I've included commands such as `docker --version, docker info, docker login, and docker build`. While these commands execute successfully when run directly on the EC2 instance, I encounter a "protocol not available" error when running them through the GitLab Runner.

To ensure the Docker daemon's functionality on the EC2 instance, I executed the command `Get-Service Docker` within the runner job, which confirmed that the Docker service is running, displaying:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  Docker             Docker Engine
```

Despite this, I'm still facing the protocol error when executing Docker commands through the GitLab Runner. Any insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the runner as a service? And what user account are you using to run the gitlab-runner service?

Comment: yes, gitlab-runner runs as a service and user account is LocalSystem

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here. It's because the DOCKER_HOST was configured incorrectly in the runner job configuration. For Windows, it should be set to `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/`, or you don't need to configure it at all, in which case the runner service accesses Docker through the default host.